# Tensorflow debugger, mouse click not working

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am following the instruction about Tensorflow debugger on `https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger`. I am able to get output (screenshot shown below)
However, the mouse click does not work and nothing happens when I click on the tensor names. I am sshing to a remote server and I'm on Tensorflow 1.3. What am I missing?

[image]